# Data Format Error while Importing JSON to excel

Tags: json, excel, import

I am trying to import data from JSON files into excel but this error occurs every time. I am in need of some way to solve this issue, any help would be much appreciated.
[image]

[image]

Comment: Looks like there is an issue with your JSON.  Suggest you load the raw JSON into one of the many online validators to determine the problem.

Comment: That seems to be OK I guess

Comment: Without the failing json document, further help will not be possible.